# AdWhirl update viewControllerForPresentingModalView

Tags: singleton, admob, iad, viewcontroller, adwhirl

I've implemented a singleton to display adWhirl ads. However, when I change scenes in my storyboard app, the viewController for the ad is not updated until a new ad is requested. I have viewControllerForPresentingModalView implemented in the singleton and I set it with displayVC on every viewdDidLoad. But since the VC is not changed until a new ad is requested, any previous ads (specifically admob) cannot display fullscreen because their VC is set to the previous scene. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
adWhirlSingleton *adWhirlSingle = [adWhirlSingleton sharedAdSingleton];
adWhirlSingle.displayVC = self;
[adWhirlSingle adjustAdSize:0 :self.view.frame.size.height -50];
[self.view addSubview:adWhirlSingle.awView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:adWhirlSingle.awView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your ViewControllers part of some containing View Controller by any chance (are they in a Navigation Controller or a Tabbed Controller for example?). If they are, I'd recommend just setting the displayVC to be the containing View Controller so you don't have to change it.

If not, maybe something like what is outlined [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html) would help. Basically creating a proxy type of class that then forwards the correct messages to the currently selected ViewController?